# object not found laravel 5.2 run on php 7.2 windows 10

Tags: laravel-5, frameworks

Recently, I've been downloading laravel project on github. 
after I tried to run the file on my localhost, I found error message on my browser. which look like this. 
on the first page, I didnt find any error message. but when I clicked on the menu (register, logo=in, services, any menus) I found this error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBiiP.jpg)

Comment: probably because AllowOverride is not active, try to search how to active4 it on your server

Comment: use cli method and run `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

you're having problem because the object really doesn't exist in your htdocs directory. You don't have to append xampp after localhost or 127.0.0.1 because xampp will treat it as an object or a folder under htdocs.

if you want to access your services, make sure you have a  folder under htdocs and put in your URL localhost/foldername